# Remote git branch checkout from within a git subtree

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-subtree

We've been using Heroku's review apps to help us better QA our Github issues but recently we switched from one app to two (1 backend, 1 frontend). Often times an issue in one repo will have two PRs (one from each repo) and both will be needed to test the issue.

This has caused me to rethink how we get a single "review app" to work with two separate repos and still have a review app that is unique for each individual Github issue we have.

My current plan is to use [Gitlab's review apps feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/). I'll leave out some of the details for brevity but the problem I'm struggling with right now is how do have one repo that contains two children sub-repos?

I've looked into `git subtree` but I'm struggling with pulling in the remote branches and running `git checkout` on the remote branches I need. When I run checkout from within a subtree it replaces all the contents of the folder.

```
+-- parent-repo <git checkout 14-parent-branch>
|   +-- child-repo-frontend <git checkout 142-frontend-branch>
|   +-- child-repo-backend <git checkout 22-backend-branch>
```

^^^ This is ideally what I want. The frontend subtree is checking out a remote branch from the remote frontend repo, same for the backend, and the parent-repo is in its own branch to save that state essentially.

I realize this might be a little long and tough to describe, please let me know if I can better clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have one separate repo for each platform, I don't know what's the reason to do this if you want to do this you can create two folders in your repo one for back-end and another for front-end.

Comment: You're right, of course it would be better to have them in two separate repos. The only reason I'm trying to have them in one repo is because I'm not aware of any other way to have Gitlab launch 1 review app from 2 separate repos. If that's possible though Im open to another solution